# Нужно ли использовать PHPDoc в современном PHP?

Tags: php

Должен ли я использовать `@param` и `@return` в приведенном ниже примере или это будет избыточный?

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 * 
 * @param string $slug
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function show(string $post): \Illuminate\View\View
{
    $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)
                ->where('status', 1) // 
                ->with('reviews')
                ->firstOrFail();

    return view('post.show', compact('post'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо чётко понимать зачем это всё надо. Писать phpDoc абсолютно на все методы - не имеет смысла никакого. Например если это простой геттер, без всякой логики внутри.

Однако то, что в методе прописаны типы входного и выходного параметра - никак не должен влиять на то, нужен phpDoc или нет. Ведь предназначения немного разные. В phpDoc надо часто описывать что за параметры передаются на вход, какое у них предназначение, часто приводятся примеры как правильно должнен быть сформирован этот параметр, какие альтернативы есть и т.д. То есть описательная часть может быть даже порой очень обширной. Иначе другие разрабы не поймут как пользоваться им (да и сам потом можешь не вспомнить)

Также phpDoc  просто обязательно надо будет сформировать на какое-нибудь публичное использование. Иначе ни один разработчик в мире не поймёт что это за параметр, зачем он нужен и как его праивильно передать. В голых методах без описания в какой-нибудь системе просто не захочется разбираться и легче будет взять другую.

В общем: да, phpDoc нужен, но **не на всё подряд** (если только это не чьё-либо требование), т.к. там не только указывается не только тип, но и бывает вспомогательная информация

---

Вот например описание метода `where` в фреймворке *Yii2*

```
/**
 * Sets the WHERE part of the query.
 *
 * The `$condition` specified as an array can be in one of the following two formats:
 *
 * - hash format: `['column1' => value1, 'column2' => value2, ...]`
 * - operator format: `[operator, operand1, operand2, ...]`
 *
 * A condition in hash format represents the following SQL expression in general:
 * `column1=value1 AND column2=value2 AND ...`. In case when a value is an array,
 * an `IN` expression will be generated. And if a value is `null`, `IS NULL` will be used
 * in the generated expression. Below are some examples:
 *
 * - `['type' => 1, 'status' => 2]` generates `(type = 1) AND (status = 2)`.
 * - `['id' => [1, 2, 3], 'status' => 2]` generates `(id IN (1, 2, 3)) AND (status = 2)`.
 * - `['status' => null]` generates `status IS NULL`.
 *
 * A condition in operator format generates the SQL expression according to the specified operator, which
 * can be one of the following:
 *
 * - **and**: the operands should be concatenated together using `AND`. For example,
 *   `['and', 'id=1', 'id=2']` will generate `id=1 AND id=2`. If an operand is an array,
 *   it will be converted into a string using the rules described here. For example,
 *   `['and', 'type=1', ['or', 'id=1', 'id=2']]` will generate `type=1 AND (id=1 OR id=2)`.
 *   The method will *not* do any quoting or escaping.
 *
 * - **or**: similar to the `and` operator except that the operands are concatenated using `OR`. For example,
 *   `['or', ['type' => [7, 8, 9]], ['id' => [1, 2, 3]]]` will generate `(type IN (7, 8, 9) OR (id IN (1, 2, 3)))`.
 *
 * - **not**: this will take only one operand and build the negation of it by prefixing the query string with `NOT`.
 *   For example `['not', ['attribute' => null]]` will result in the condition `NOT (attribute IS NULL)`.
 *
 * - **between**: operand 1 should be the column name, and operand 2 and 3 should be the
 *   starting and ending values of the range that the column is in.
 *   For example, `['between', 'id', 1, 10]` will generate `id BETWEEN 1 AND 10`.
 *
 * - **not between**: similar to `between` except the `BETWEEN` is replaced with `NOT BETWEEN`
 *   in the generated condition.
 *
 * - **in**: operand 1 should be a column or DB expression, and operand 2 be an array representing
 *   the range of the values that the column or DB expression should be in. For example,
 *   `['in', 'id', [1, 2, 3]]` will generate `id IN (1, 2, 3)`.
 *   The method will properly quote the column name and escape values in the range.
 *
 *   To create a composite `IN` condition you can use and array for the column name and value, where the values are indexed by the column name:
 *   `['in', ['id', 'name'], [['id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo'], ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'bar']] ]`.
 *
 *   You may also specify a sub-query that is used to get the values for the `IN`-condition:
 *   `['in', 'user_id', (new Query())->select('id')->from('users')->where(['active' => 1])]`
 *
 * - **not in**: similar to the `in` operator except that `IN` is replaced with `NOT IN` in the generated condition.
 *
 * - **like**: operand 1 should be a column or DB expression, and operand 2 be a string or an array representing
 *   the values that the column or DB expression should be like.
 *   For example, `['like', 'name', 'tester']` will generate `name LIKE '%tester%'`.
 *   When the value range is given as an array, multiple `LIKE` predicates will be generated and concatenated
 *   using `AND`. For example, `['like', 'name', ['test', 'sample']]` will generate
 *   `name LIKE '%test%' AND name LIKE '%sample%'`.
 *   The method will properly quote the column name and escape special characters in the values.
 *   Sometimes, you may want to add the percentage characters to the matching value by yourself, you may supply
 *   a third operand `false` to do so. For example, `['like', 'name', '%tester', false]` will generate `name LIKE '%tester'`.
 *
 * - **or like**: similar to the `like` operator except that `OR` is used to concatenate the `LIKE`
 *   predicates when operand 2 is an array.
 *
 * - **not like**: similar to the `like` operator except that `LIKE` is replaced with `NOT LIKE`
 *   in the generated condition.
 *
 * - **or not like**: similar to the `not like` operator except that `OR` is used to concatenate
 *   the `NOT LIKE` predicates.
 *
 * - **exists**: operand 1 is a query object that used to build an `EXISTS` condition. For example
 *   `['exists', (new Query())->select('id')->from('users')->where(['active' => 1])]` will result in the following SQL expression:
 *   `EXISTS (SELECT "id" FROM "users" WHERE "active"=1)`.
 *
 * - **not exists**: similar to the `exists` operator except that `EXISTS` is replaced with `NOT EXISTS` in the generated condition.
 *
 * - Additionally you can specify arbitrary operators as follows: A condition of `['>=', 'id', 10]` will result in the
 *   following SQL expression: `id >= 10`.
 *
 * **Note that this method will override any existing WHERE condition. You might want to use [[andWhere()]] or [[orWhere()]] instead.**
 *
 * @param array $condition the conditions that should be put in the WHERE part.
 * @return $this the query object itself
 * @see andWhere()
 * @see orWhere()
 */
public function where($condition);
```